# How to make animated buttons in a menu with Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d, cocos2d-iphone

How do I make animated menus with cocos2d, I just want to animate the buttons and not the entire scene. Effects I look for is flipping buttons (like the back of the button is the next menu), buttons that retract once selected and re appear with new button.

Basically what I ask for is cool effects between menu transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a FiniteAction from a Sequence and make the sprite asociated to the button play it on touch. Use the different classes available for different effects.

For the back-to-back you need two buttons, one drawn on top of the other with different priorities. Make one do a FlipY while the other does a flipY reverse and change the drawing priority.

Retract is just a Scale or Skew effect.