# How to create fun and interactive menus with cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make animated buttons in a menu with Cocos2d?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/how-to-make-animated-buttons-in-a-menu-with-cocos2d)

How do I make fun and interactive menus with cocos2d, all the tutorials are just for simple clickable menus. Can any one help me learn this?

It would be see the menu flip or slide away, I know you can do this with scenes but how do I make this with just the menu?

Let's say the menu is a bunch of cards and I want them to flip over like the sub-menu is on the backside of the card, how would I do this?

Or, make the Main menu slide in from the left, right, top or bottom side and then when a button is selected it slides away the same way and switch to a sub-menu (settings, Score etc)?

Anyone?

David

Comment: What are you asking specifically? for algorithms to do some kind of transitions?